# 'toggle()' not working correctly, (shrinks the div off of the screen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the segment of my code that is not working:

```
//code for div 3
//When clicked the div will double in size and the text within will change and then when clicked again, all will revert back to original
$('#div3').toggle(function(){
    $('#div3').animate({height: '300px', width: '300px'});
    document.getElementById('change-me').innerHTML="Click me to make me smaller!";
},
function(){
    $('#div3').animate({height: '150px', width: '150px'});
    document.getElementById('change-me').innerHTML="Click me to mke me bigger!";
});
```

Whenever I refresh the page to see if it is working, the div that this code is applied too shrinks and fades off of the page towards the top right corner...

Thanks to anyone that helps me. 
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, toggle is not function to achieve this. try this one

```js
function big() {
  $('#div3').animate({
    height: '300px',
    width: '300px'
  });
  document.getElementById('change-me').innerHTML = "Click me to make me smaller!";
  $('#div3').off('click', big).on('click', small);
}

function small() {
  $('#div3').animate({
    height: '150px',
    width: '150px'
  });
  document.getElementById('change-me').innerHTML = "Click me to mke me bigger!";
  $('#div3').off('click', small).on('click', big);
}

$('#div3').on('click', big);
```

```css
div#div3 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="div3">
  <div id="change-me">
    click me
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

The major problem with the original code is that its using the `toggle` function, which according to the documentation is to

> display or hide the matched elements.

It looks like what you want is to toggle the size of `div3` on click, like this

version added: 1.0

```js
let currSize = "small";
let config = {
  small: {
    size: {
      height: '150px',
      width: '150px'
    },
    msg: "Click me to make me bigger!"
  },
  big: {
    size: {
      height: '300px',
      width: '300px'
    },
    msg: "Click me to make me smaller!"
  }
};


$('#div3').click((e) => {
  // toggle the current size
  currSize = (currSize == "small") ? "big" : "small";
  
  // animate to the new size
  $('#div3').animate(config[currSize].size);
  
  // update the change-me text
  document.getElementById('change-me').innerHTML = config[currSize].msg;
});
```

```css
#div3 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(64,64,64,0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div3">
  Awesomest div ever, really, the best.
  <div id="change-me">Click me to make me bigger!</div>
</div>
```